# &nbsp; showing as blank space in Wordpress IDE (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to remove non-breaking spaces on a Wordpress site with jQuery + RegEx. I'm using the 'Custom CSS and JS' plugin. I know how to do this with code -- however, whenever I save the function dealing with `&nbsp;`, it's re-rendered as a blank space in the IDE! So annoying!

Anyway, here's what I would use if I could:

```
$("p").html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
});
```

but it keeps getting re-rendered as this every time I save:

```
$("p").html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

And here's my current (dangerous) workaround -- splitting it into two. Obviously this is a terrible long-term solution:

```
$("p").html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/&n/g, '');
});

$("p").html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/bsp;/g, '');
});
```

I don't think targeting blank spaces works for non-breaking spaces; plus, how would avoid getting rid of ALL spaces on the page?

And the `:empty` jQuery selector doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the IDE", but if it's processing your entities, I would think `&amp;nbsp;` should work.

Comment: var myText = $("p").text();
      var newMyText = myText.replace(/ /g,'');